# Calabi-Yau structure on cotangent bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth (compact) manifold, my question is when the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ has a Calabi-Yau structure.

Certain constructions are known, for instance, if $M=\Sigma\times S^1$ or $M$ is a compact rank 1 symmetric space, then $T^*M$ admits a Kahler structure with a compatible Ricci-flat metric. I am mostly interested in the case $M$ is of real dimension 3.

I am wondering if there are any obstruction to the existence of Calabi-Yau structure on $T^*M$?

Comment: The following paper (posted today!) might be of interest: http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7394